# TypeScript strict member type check on dynamically indexed object

Tags: typescript, vuex

I've got following scenario, I'm developing a vuex plugin in TypeScript to automatically fetch required data from server.
This is my state definition:

```
export interface RootState {
    users: { [id: string]: User };
    someNestedSection: {
        currentUserAccount: Account
    }
}
```

And I've created type for object describing how to fetch these resources:

```
export type RemoteOptions<T> = {
    readonly [K in keyof T]?: RemoteOptions<T[K]>|{ fetchResource: (queryData?: any) => T[K]|any };
};
```

So my `RemoteOptions<T>` object can look like this:

```
const options: RemoteOptions<RootState> = {
    users: {
        fetchResource: (userId: number) => 'this is NOT strictly checked'
    },
    someNestedSection: {
        currentUserAccount: {
            fetchResource: () => new Account(/* some data from server */)
        }
    }
}
```

My `RemoteOptions<T>` definition provides nice type checking for almost everything, it enforces `RemoteOptions<RootState>` object to contain only those properties that `RootState` has (including nested ones) and it is even able enforce (if there was no `|any` at the return type) `fetchResource` function at `options.someNestedSection.currentUserAccount` to return only `Account` objects but I've got NO idea how to enforce `User` return value on `options.users.fetchResource`.
Problem lies in return type of `fetchResource: (queryData?: any) => T[K]|any`, I've got `any` there and I need to replace `any` with something like `memberof T[K]` but I've got no clue what it should be (there's no `memberof` operator in TypeScript, there's only `keyof`, but it doesn't apply in this scenario).

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured this one out :)

New definition is:

```
readonly [K in keyof T]?: RemoteOptions<T[K]>|{ fetchResource: (queryData?: any) => T[K]|T[K][any] };
```

So I force TypeScript to strictly check if return value is instance of `T[K][any]` which I believe means "type of any member of `T[K]`".

And it seems to work. I hope it's correct approach, if it is not, I'd be grateful if someone would point it out to me.